# jQuery UI - I can't style checkbox button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, checkbox

So Im having a problem with the button() function.

HTML:

```
<input id="nextday_button" name="nextday" type="checkbox" value="true" /><label for="nextday_button">yes</label> 
<input id="submit_button" name="commit" type="submit" value="Check" />
```

JS:

```
$("#nextday_button").button().css('font-size','36px');
$("#submit_button").button().css({'font-size':'22px', 'padding': '3px 12px 3px 12px'});
```

The styling for the #submit_button is working perfectly, but I cant style the #nextday_button. .css() seems not working in this case. Am I doing something wrong in the HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, thanks to Ghyath Serhal I found that I can't style the 'button' itself this way:

```
$("#nextday_button").button().css('font-size','36px');
```

because this code is only styling the checkbox. I should style the label instead, so I assigned an ID to the label and then changed the JS to:

```
$("#nextday_button").button();
$("#nextday_label").css('font-size', '36px');
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to remove the .Button().
Try this $("#nextday_button").css('font-size','36px');